# Split a string with key value pairs

Tags: powershell

I have this string read from a text file. How can I get the value of each both keys?

```
statusId=0  statusError=Info: Using ID '8d07afe6-4fc3-47a3-9583-571f79ca15ae' for connections to the remote server.
```

I can not do an easy split on whitespace or a semicolon due to the content.

Comment: you should probably post what you want the output to look like...

Comment: I need the value of both keys. I do not care for the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to split on the keys:

```
$statusId,$statusError = $string -split 'statusId=|statusError='
```

Comment: cool code and learned sth new today about powershell. Just tested it works! Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea why or what actually I changed not much code, but now its not working anymore :/ I get: statuscode: 
 ------------------------
 statusmessage:  0  Info: Using ID , The ZERO number should actually after the "statuscode:" but its not? damn it worked before... that is my code: $statusCode,$statusMessage = $statusContent -split 'statusCode=|statusMessage='

Comment: Looks like you may have something unexpected in your input.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is always of form

```
statusId=<numbers> statusError=<whatever>
```

it can be splitted with a regex using `-match` operator. If the string format changes, this approach needs tuning for the regex so be careful.

You don't specify what `key` means, so I guess `statusId` and `statusError` are keys.

Like so,

```
$s = "statusId=0  statusError=Info: Using ID '8d07afe6-4fc3-47a3-9583-571f79ca15ae' for connections to the remote server." # Hard-coded data for demo
$s -match "^(statusId=\d+\s+)(.+)"
# Output
True

$Matches
# Output
Name           Value
----           -----
2              statusError=Info: Using ID '8d07afe6-4fc3-47a3-9583-571f79ca15ae' for connections to ...
1              statusId=0
0              statusId=0  statusError=Info: Using ID '8d07afe6-4fc3-47a3-9583-571f79ca15ae' for con...
$Matches[1]
# Output
statusId=0
$Matches[2]
# Output
statusError=Info: Using ID '8d07afe6-4fc3-47a3-9583-571f79ca15ae' for connections to the remote server.
($Matches[2] -split '=')[1]
# Output
Info: Using ID '8d07afe6-4fc3-47a3-9583-571f79ca15ae' for connections to the remote server.
```

The pattern `"^(statusId=\d+\s+)(.+)"` looks for string starting with `statusId=`, at least one number followed with at least one whitespace and then anything goes. Accessing results is done via [automatic](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$Matches` variable. The match is then splitted into two parts with `-split '='` and by using the `[1]` indexer, the "Info: " part is reached.